# Set the position of a label within a cell in tableview

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a tableview with dynamic cells. I have added a label in a cell.

The label is always placed in centre of the cell.

I don't want it to be dynamically placed when I adjust the height of the row.

I would like to place the label 20px under the top of the cell.

How can I do this?

Comment: Read this tutorial. https://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: Add a 20 px constraint of y position to top.

Comment: This is a very standard use of `Autolayout`. There are lots of tutorials on `Autolayout` and how to use `Constraints` on the Internet. I suggest you carry out an Internet search and work your way through a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can set constraints like `top,leading,trailing and fixed height` to that label if you are using autolayout.

Put your label in cell with 20 pixel of distance from top and then set constraints or pin constraints as mentioned above.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Auto Layouts in your StoryBoard. Like these

[image]

[image]

[image]

You have to setup all the constraints in the storyboard to make it work properly.

Comment: thanks for comment.  i know i can adjust the cell by giving constraint. but the height of the row is dynamic in my project. i want the label always to be placed 20 px below the top of the cell. is there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use autolayout, set constraint.

Select label and Drag to upper of label by pushing control.

When popup appears, push option key.

Click "Top Space to Container"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5tFs.png)

Select label and look into size inspector. Modify constant value of "Top Space To" constraint to 20.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsHUJ.png)

Comment: thanks for comment.  i know i can adjust the cell by giving constraint. but the height of the row is dynamic in my project. i want the label always to be placed 20 px below the top of the cell. is there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If using **Auto Layouts**, give these **4 constraints**, it will work.

Drop the **label** on custom cell where exactly you want, give **top space, tailing and leading and also a fixed height**.

[image]

Comment: thanks for comment.  i know i can adjust the cell by giving constraint. but the height of the row is dynamic in my project. i want the label always to be placed 20 px below the top of the cell. is there any ways to do that?

Comment: Drag your label to 20px down i.e Top Space to is 20px then it will be always 20px from top of cell.